# How to make a command time counter

Tags: discord.js

My question is: how can I make a command clock (when you execute `!count` and after 4 minutes you type `!time` and it says 4 minutes!) in discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

exports.run = (client, message) => {
  var af = 0;

  a = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("Hi");
  af = af+1;

   if(af == 25){
     clearInterval(a);
  }
  console.log(af);
  }, 60000);
};

exports.help = {
  name: 'time',
  description: 'time?',
  usage: 'time'
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this: when you execute `!count` you save the server time, when you execute `!time` you send back the difference between those two dates.

Pseudo-code:

```js
var date;

if (command == 'count') {
  date = new Date();
  message.reply("Done");
}

if (command == 'time') {
  let result = require('pretty-ms')(date ? (new Date() - date) : 0);
  message.reply(result);
}
```

I'm using the `pretty-ms` npm package to format milliseconds: [docs & live demo](https://npm.runkit.com/pretty-ms).

When someone calls `!count`, store the current Date somewhere. `new Date() - date` will give you the difference between the current time and the time you stored, in milliseconds.
Please note that if the commands are in different files, as it seems by the code you posted, you'll need to store the date in a location accessible to both files: one of the solutions is to store the date as a global variable.

```js
// by '...' I mean that you can put it wherever you want in the global object
global['...'].date = new Date():
new Date() - global['...'].date
```

**Edit: `Date` class explanation**
When you create a new `Date`, it saves the time at the moment you create it. It's like saying *"`!count` was executed at 04:20"*. When you want to check how much time has passed, you need to calculate the first date minus the current date: *"`!count` was executed at 04:20. Now it's 05:40, so the difference is `05:40 - 04:20 = 01:20`: it's 1 hour and 20 minutes since you first executed `!count`"*. That translates to `new Date() - past_date = time_passed`.
Since dates are stored in milliseconds that difference is in milliseconds: if you want to make it more readable, you can format it by using a function as the `'pretty-ms'` package, or similar ones.
The key concept is:

- When `!count` is called, you save a `new Date()` to lock that point in time
- When `!time` is called, you get the difference by doing `new Date() - past_date`

Comment: I edited my answer: I tried to explain more how date work in JavaScript, hope that this makes it clearer

Comment: so now, to use it in different command files is a little bit confusing, if you could explain the global option

Comment: global[date].date = new Date();
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'date' of undefined

Comment: and i get 0 ms always should i modify something?

Comment: You can use `global.date = new Date();` If you want to put it in another object, you need to declare that object too: `global.commands = {date: new Date()};` Keep in mind that if you replace `date` with that, you need to change it everywhere

Comment: Happy to hear that :)